# Reading files in C# Mono Debian not working

Tags: c#, linux, file-io, mono

I'm using MonoDevelop on Debian, I've problem with following piece of code:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.Open(e.FullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)))
```

It is working fine in Windows and fine when run through MonoDevelop. But if I run it like `mono output.exe` or sudo `mono output.exe` first time method with this code is called it works fine. But second time it fails. It don't write anything no exception is thrown. I've also tried replacing `using` by `try catch finally` but no exception is thrown. I think that it just cannot read the file.

Method with this code is called by FileSystemWatcher change event. And I'm changing the file through VIM.

Any ideas how can I find out where the problem is? Why in MonoDevelop it works just fine (so I cannot trace it) and if run from Terminal it works just for first time (the method is called always but file is not read and no exception is thrown it does not even enter inside using{ }).

Thanks!

Comment: Two things I'd investigate: 1. Maybe the FileSystemWatcher event is not being dispatched when you think it is, and 2. Perhaps File.Open blocks in certain cases when attempting to open files.

Comment: @Rob I've been tracing FileSystemWatcher event through Console.WriteLine it is fired but the using (StreamReader ....) line is skipped and nothing else is done. It is like there would be `return`. I've been using just StreamReader and it was doing this problem so I've tried using File.Open stream to add Mode and Access conditions but it didn't change. Should I try some other method of reading files?

Comment: Which mono version are you using?

Comment: @RobertN 3.2.8 (Debian 3.2.8+dfsg-4+rpi1)

Answer (score 0):

Under 3.2.8 I am hitting a different issue relating to the file watcher events not firing (known issue that was fixed). Using 3.12.1 or 4.0.x+ the following code works fine for me, but that is not on a R-PI. Give it a shot on your RPI-Debian/Mono 3.2.8 install to see if it is a R-PI related bug/issue.

### Example output (Ctrl-C to exit):

```
>>mcs Program.cs
>>mono Program.exe 
Created watcher for /var/folders/hc/xf7j8x7j72dg7g098mwkhbs40000gp/T/tmp438e6660.tmp
Changed: '/var/folders/hc/xf7j8x7j72dg7g098mwkhbs40000gp/T/tmp438e6660.tmp', type: Changed
0Changed: '/var/folders/hc/xf7j8x7j72dg7g098mwkhbs40000gp/T/tmp438e6660.tmp', type: Changed
01Changed: '/var/folders/hc/xf7j8x7j72dg7g098mwkhbs40000gp/T/tmp438e6660.tmp', type: Changed
012Changed: '/var/folders/hc/xf7j8x7j72dg7g098mwkhbs40000gp/T/tmp438e6660.tmp', type: Changed
0123Changed: '/var/folders/hc/xf7j8x7j72dg7g098mwkhbs40000gp/T/tmp438e6660.tmp', type: Changed
```

### Example Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FileWatcher
{
    class Program
    {
        static int counter = 0;

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            var tempDir = Path.GetTempPath ();
            var tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName ();
            var fsw = new FileSystemWatcher (tempDir, Path.GetFileName (tempFile));
            fsw.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Size;
            fsw.Changed += WatcherOnChanged;
            fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            Console.WriteLine ("Created watcher for {0}", tempFile);
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource ();
            Console.CancelKeyPress += (s, e) => {
                e.Cancel = true;
                cts.Cancel ();
            };    
            MainAsync (tempFile, cts.Token).Wait ();
            fsw.Dispose ();
            File.Delete (tempFile);
        }

        static async Task MainAsync (string fileName, CancellationToken token)
        {
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested) {
                WriteFile (fileName);
                Thread.Sleep (2000);
            }
        }

        private static void WatcherOnChanged (object sender, FileSystemEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Changed: '{0}', type: {1}", eventArgs.FullPath, eventArgs.ChangeType);
            ReadFile (eventArgs.FullPath);
        }

        private static void ReadFile (string fileName)
        {
            using (var sr = new StreamReader (File.Open (fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))) {
                Console.Write (sr.ReadLine ());
            }
        }

        private static void WriteFile (string fileName)
        {
            using (var sr = new StreamWriter (fileName, true)) {
                sr.Write (counter++);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've temporary solved that problem by removing and recreating file instead of editing. Now it can access the file without a problem. Here is my output: http://pastebin.com/sgGCK6Md